# Firefox snap stays version 99 in Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: updates, 22.04, kubuntu, firefox, snap

On a secondary laptop I am running LTS Kubuntu 22.04 and the default Firefox snap - while for various reasons I don't use Firefox snap on my first laptop, the main one being that I can manage more easily Plasma integration of a non-snap Firefox version. But I'm ready to learn and I want to test if there's any truth in many people's dismissing of Ubuntu's (especially Firefox's) snap push.

And it started badly. The system is newly installed, updated and restarted, but what I have here is version 99 - from before the whole new-addons button! Even ESR is 115.

Normally Firefox should update itself.

[image]

```
sudo snap refresh

All snaps up to date.

firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 99.0.1


snap info firefox
name:      firefox
summary:   Mozilla Firefox web browser
publisher: Mozilla✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/firefox
license:   unset
description: |
  Firefox is a powerful, extensible web browser with support for modern web
  application technologies.
commands:
  - firefox
snap-id:      3wdHCAVyZEmYsCMFDE9qt92UV8rC8Wdk
tracking:     latest/stable/ubuntu-22.04
refresh-date: 58 days ago, at 18:18 CEST
channels:
  latest/stable:    120.0.1-1    2023-11-30 (3504) 254MB -
  latest/candidate: 120.0.1-1    2023-11-29 (3504) 254MB -
  latest/beta:      121.0b5-1    2023-11-29 (3501) 258MB -
  latest/edge:      122.0a1      2023-11-29 (3494) 290MB -
  esr/stable:       115.5.0esr-1 2023-11-21 (3392) 253MB -
  esr/candidate:    115.5.0esr-1 2023-11-14 (3392) 253MB -
  esr/beta:         ↑                                    
  esr/edge:         ↑                                    
installed:          99.0.1-1                (1232) 163MB -
```

Comment: If you run `snap info firefox` what do you get?   On my system with `firefox --version` I'm getting 120.0 which matches the results of my `snap info` request.  (*I wonder if your system has failed to upgrade [connect to snap store in order to do so] as it can report as snaps up to date in that case, though quick check & firefox 103 was provided on 22.04 released ISO, 99 maybe an pre-release ISO though; ie. your original installed version maybe*)

Comment: @guiverc - See updated question/body. That I have 99 is no surprise as I don't have the addons button. But 120 is in 'channels'. why doesn't it get updated?

Comment: @guiverc - My Kubuntu is recently installed, I don't think that I had an old ISO. But the system is fully upgraded.

Comment: Why it's not updating I'd love to help you with; the only thing I can offer is that Ubuntu Servers have had issues of late (*on occasion*) which can cause 50x errors or timeouts, that cause any *snap refresh* to report no updates are available, but in time will work normally..  ie. maybe try again later...   I believe your 99 is from pre-release media, eg. I see `jammy-desktop-canary-amd64.manifest:snap:firefox        stable/ubuntu-22.04     1232` on a SCAN of the *canary* installer ISO for 22.04 (what is `ubuntu-desktop-installer` for 23.04 & later) with **1232** matching your version !!!

Comment: @guiverc - Thanks. It might be that I had an old iso on a USB stick, doubt it but seems the only explanation. I'll try later although I have already downloaded the 'portable' firefox from Mozilla. :)

Comment: FYI:  *I'm not saying you used the CANARY 22.04 ISO at all; I just did a `grep` on my `ubuntu_64` folder which has ~40 ISOs at various times/milestones etc & the **1232** you provided was detected on that ISO I have locally  (*it may not be the only one, but the ISOs using `ubiquity` will have been updated more regularly for jammy*)

Comment: @guiverc - No matter my ISO, the `sudo snap firefox` lists 120 under `channels`. The system should get up to date no matter my installation ISO.

Comment: As already indicated, I see your issue on *failure to update* as *network related*, ie. either your local network, ISP OR an issue with Ubuntu Servers I previously mentioned (*given I've had the 'snaps are up to date' when I know they're not because of network issues myself*) but they were resolved when tried again (*by fourth re-try in worst case a short delay later*). My 4th re-try issue  coincided with an ISP issue in my case so it may not have just been Ubuntu Servers alone...   My 2c.

Comment: @guiverc - I have fixed it by removing Firefox and installing it back. In this way I lost my profile settings and had to resync and recustomize, but 120 was installed.

Comment: @user535733 - Firefox was not running. But normally Firefox and all Ff-based browsers are able to check for updates by themselves, automatically or when we go to "Help - About Firefox". Update is applied *after* restarting the browser. The problem above was no update was found and I'm not sure it will find them in the future unless I re-install. (Now I'm writing on a different laptop. in a portable Ff v.120 which has just found the 120.0.1 update and is asking me to restart the browser.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo snap remove firefox
snap install --stable firefox
```

Removing Firefox and installing it back made me lose my profile settings and had to resync and recustomize, but latest 120 version was installed.

I hope I don't have to do it manually next time, or it's https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/linux/, which I'm sure gets updated by itself.